# Access service in remote Kubernetes cluster using ingress

Tags: kubernetes

I'm attempting to access a service in an existing kubernetes cluster deployed in a remote machine. I've configured the cluster to be accessible through kubectl from my local mac.

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.58.114:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.58.114:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

The ingress configuration for the service I want to connect is:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: gw-ingress
  namespace: vick-system
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/vick-system/ingresses/gw-ingress
  uid: 52b62da6-01c1-11e9-9f59-fa163eb296d8
  resourceVersion: '2695'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2018-12-17T06:02:23Z'
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity":"cookie","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash":"sha1","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name":"route"},"name":"gw-ingress","namespace":"vick-system"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"wso2-apim-gateway","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"gateway","servicePort":8280},"path":"/"}]}}],"tls":[{"hosts":["wso2-apim-gateway"]}]}}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: sha1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: route
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - wso2-apim-gateway
  rules:
    - host: wso2-apim-gateway
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: gateway
              servicePort: 8280
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 172.17.17.100
```

My list of services are:
[image]

My /etc/hosts file looks like below:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

172.17.17.100 wso2-apim-gateway wso2-apim wso2sp-dashboard
```

What is the URL I should use to access this service from my local browser? Should I do any more configurations?

Comment: on what environment is your cluster running? is this kubeadm?

Comment: I managed to get this done by changing the external ip of the ingress-nginx service to the IP of the host. Then I updated /etc/hosts entry shown above replacing 172.17.17.100 of the above IP(of the remote host)

Comment: so the problem is fixed now?

Comment: Yes. It is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access this would be a port-forward, which requires no modification of your hosts file.

`kubectl -n vick-system port-forward svc/wso2sp-dashboard 9643`

This will allow you to browse to `http://localhost:9643` and access that service.

Please note, the `svc/name` syntax is only supported in `kubectl >= 1.10`

Comment: I tried this already. When I hit the localhost:9763 the url does become wso2-apim-gateway but browser shows cant reach error after some time.